# Norton Security Suite Symantec Download Manager Error: "Error writing to disk"

Tags: windows-7, norton-antivirus

My broadband provider (Comcast) decided to switch their 'included with service' security suite from McAfee to Norton Security Suite.  Their email directed me to a site that downloaded the Symantec Download Manager (NortonDL.exe) and that went fine.  I'm running Windows 7 32-bit and running this application pops up the standard User Account Control message and the software is correctly identified as coming from Symantec.  I answer 'yes' to allow the software to install and upon launch immediately get an "Error writing to disk" error.  I searched the Internet for this error, but mainly I find Comcast users complaining about the same issue with no resolution other than to call Symantec.  I found no one suggesting a successful workaround and it appeared that most of the support calls took up to three hours.  I'd like to avoid that if possible.  Ideas?

To be honest, I'm getting close to bagging this installation and just moving to Microsoft Security Essentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem on Windows 7 x64 and Vista 32 machines.

Here's how I solved it:

1-downloaded Norton removal tool from Symantec and ran it.
2-searched C drive for Symant and deleted any files/folders that looked remotely related to Symantec. Included systems folders in the search
3-repeated search & delete using Norton 
4-performed same search & delete strategy on registry via regedit for both Symant and Norton
5-cleared all temporary internet files
6-rebooted
7-downloaded Norton install and ran it successfully this time

Overkill? Maybe, but it worked on two different machines that were having the same error.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I ended up going with Microsoft Security Essentials but I believe your solution would have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the machine is in limited mode and doesn't have permission to write to the correct folder?  See Control Panel > Users or cacls.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is even worse.  One day after I installed Norton from Comcast I got an irretrievable blue screen of death boot error message.  The only solution since I was unable to boot into Windows (using Win 7 64 bit) was to format/reinstall the OS.  After re-installing my usual software (MS Outlook & Office & several others), on 3 separate occasions I got a blue screen of death again (Bad_Pool_Header) when I went to install s/w that had previously worked on my system prior to Norton.  Even Java wouldn't install without causing a BSOD!

I uninstalled Norton and PooF!  All the problematic s/w reinstalled without a hitch...  Now I'm back to using McAfee (my recently-purchased Dell came w/ a 15-moth subscription, so I activated it).  Until proven otherwise, Norton has been nothing by trouble for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.... 1 day after installing Norton 360, blue screen!
I spent an hour or so on the phone with Norton was eventually referred to a supervisor who identified the problem to be the program SONIC DLA.   I beleive it is a CD recording software that came stock on my computer (Dell, about 5+ yrs old, running Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3).

After removing Sonic DLA from my computer, and removing all traces of Sonic DLA from the registry (as well as Mcafee and Malware Bytes), and then re-downloading & re-installing Norton 360, the problem seems to have been fixed.

Hope this saves someone else a little time & frustration!